# Expo/React-native AsyncStorage.getItem() resolves to null

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm developing an app in Expo and am facing a very simple problem.

Inside of my App.js:

```
AsyncStorage.setItem("test", "testVal").then((res) => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("test", (value) => {
        console.log("VALUE: " + value);
    });
});
```

The code above logs `VALUE: null`, instead of `VALUE: test`. Any ideas on what could be going wrong?

(Using EXPO Version 3.17.21)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `getItem` signature:

```
static getItem(key: string, [callback]: ?(error: ?Error, result: ?string) => void): Promise
```

So the first argument of the callback is `error`. try:

```
AsyncStorage.setItem("test", "testVal").then((res) => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("test", (err, value) => {
        console.log("VALUE: " + value);
    });
})
```